# how to keep colour of button same when background is changed in android

Tags: android, background-color

I am developing an android app in which when I am setting a background image to that app, any thing like button or edittext also includes that background, making them difficult to see.

Following is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1,b2,b3;
    ImageView i1;
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        View background = findViewById(R.id.background);

                background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);



        }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/img2"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
       android:color="#ffffff"
        android:text="HELLO" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the color of the button and the edit-text to be same as it should be when having a plain white background.

Comment: Change the background of buttons also like `your_button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)`

Comment: @Aniruddha I want the button to remain in its original colour as it would have been when the background was white.If I am developing a bigger app, doing as you said so would mean to set background colour of each and every button and edittext

Comment: Add the following to the button and image in the XML `style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"`

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Drawable buttonBackground = b1.getBackground();

    View background = findViewById(R.id.background);
    background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
    b1.setBackgroundResource(buttonBackground);
}
```

This will work.